# HTTP Sniffing using wireshark

Tags: macos, http, wireshark, sniffing

I am using Wireshark on my Mac, which is running Yosemite. When I am sniffing the HTTP protocol, I can only see the HTTP/get and I cannot see the HTTP/OK.. Is there a way to enable this on my MAC? I know Windows users can see them by default. When I click on the packet and follow the TCP trace, I can see the info, but I cannot find the corresponding packet in the packetview.

Thanks in advance!

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoQ5p.jpg

Comment: Do you have any filters configured (either display or capture)?  Perhaps you could share a screenshot?

Comment: Hi Heavyd, Unfortunately I cannot add a screenshot, due to the lack of reputation. I do not have a capture filter enabled, and my display filter has been set to HTTP. When I do the exact same thing on a virtual machine running Windows, it is showing it properly.

Comment: post a screenshot to flikr, imgur etc & link it in your question. Someone with the required rep will inline it for you.

Comment: Alright, the screenshot has been added in my question!